# Can I use a <p>7</p> (number in a paragraph) as a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to take a number from a html paragraph and divide it by 1.2. (Basically take a vat inclusive price and replace it with a vat exclusive price).

My website app allows me to add html to the paragraph it produces with the price, so i can give the < p > an ID then style in my css, I assume I can do something similar with javaScript to change its value?

App code:

```html
<p id="excVat">[E] exc VAT</p>
```

So the app will convert this [E] as a price and display that in the paragraph, such as £3.60, and I want to then divide that by 1.2 so it would show £3.00 exc VAT.

Sorry if this is a bit basic, I'm new to javascript. Any help is much appreciated, I want to learn js but it is a lot for just solving this one problem.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, e.g. with `getElementById`

Comment: Thankyou, I'm trying to learn enough to solve this problem, good to know I'm not wasting my time and will keep trying!

Comment: read the textContent, convert to a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ex = document.getElementById('excVat').innerText.replace('£', '')

ex = parseFloat(ex.substring(0,4));

console.log((ex/1.2).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Hey it's not the most dynamic calculation but it works for your p :)